# Is there a general geometrical connection between $f(x)$ and $f(1/x)$?

Tags: geometry, graphing-functions

What is the relationship between graphs of a function $f(x)$ and the function $f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$?

If I consider $f(x)=x$, $x^2$, and $x^2-x$ and then $g(x)=f(1/x)$, especially in the last example ($x^2-x$) there is no answer clear to me.

Comment: Loosely speaking, the graph of $f(1/x)$ looks like the graph of $f(x)$ as seen from the point at infinity.

Comment: The part of the graph to the right of the $y$-axis is reflected across the line $x=1$, with the finite left-hand part ($0<x<1$) stretched out to be infinitely long, and the infinite right-hand part ($1<x<\infty$) compressed to fit into $(0,1)$. And then a similar thing happens to the part on the left of the axis.

Comment: Thank you, very nice idea  about the point of infinity. Could you please explain a bit more about it?

Comment: To get a sense of the stretching and compressing mentioned in @MJD's comment, compare $f(x)=\sin(\pi x)$ and $g(x)=\sin(\pi/x)$: the single arch between $x=0$ and $x=1$ for $f(x)$ spans $x=1$ to $x=\infty$ for $g(x)$; and the infinitely-many arches of $f(x)$ to the right of $x=1$ get squished between $x=1$ and $x=0$ for $g(x)$ ... getting more and more squished as they get closer and closer to $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make the "point at infinity" idea work you have to do the following (nothing original here, this is just the simplest instance of the so called [projective spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_space)).

Instead of just one real number $x$ consider pairs of real number $(x,y)$ except you

- exclude the pair $(0,0)$ and
- consider equal two points when one can be obtained from the other by multiplication for a real nonzero number, i.e. $(x,y)=(x^\prime,y^\prime)$ when $x^\prime=\lambda x$ and $y^\prime=\lambda y$ (same $\lambda$) for some $\lambda\neq0$.

Call $\mathbb{P}$ the set constructed in this way. Every point in the real line has a corresponding point in $\mathbb{P}$ simply as $x\mapsto (x,1)$. But $\mathbb{P}$ has an extra-point which doesn't "come from" the real line, namely the point $\infty=(1,0)$. This is the "point at infinity".

Given a function $f(x)$ for real $x$ you can define a function on $\mathbb{P}$ setting
$$
F(a,b)=f(a/b)\qquad
\text{if $b\neq0$.}
$$
In general $F$ will not be defined at $\infty$ but in some cases you can extend $F$ to a function continuous at $\infty$, namely when $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=L<\infty$.

(Mind that in this post I'm using the symbol $\infty$ with two different meanings)

Now the transformation $x\mapsto1/x$ on the real line can be read as $(x,1)\mapsto(1,x)$ on $\mathbb{P}$ which now makes sense also for $x=0$, thus $0=(0,1)$ and $\infty$ are interchanged.

Therefore, if you think the graph of $f(x)$ as "centered at $0$", the graph of $f(1/x)=F(1,x)$ is nothing but the graph of $F$ "centered at $\infty$".

Comment: Thank you very much!